# Scala implicit converter is not visible for type

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to implement an implicit converter for jackson mapper in scala,

The code looks like that:

```
object JacksonSerializer {
    implicit val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    implicit class JacksonDeSerializer(val body: AnyContent) extends AnyVal {
        def as[T](implicit manifest: Manifest[T]): T = {
          mapper.readValue(body.asText.get, manifest.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]])
        }
    }
    implicit class JacksonSerializer(val any: Any) {
        def toJsonString: String = {
          val out = new StringWriter
          mapper.writeValue(out, any)
          out.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

But when i try the following:

```
import JacksonSerializer.JacksonSerializer
Ok("{}".toJsonString)
```

I get a compilation error:

```
value toJsonString is not a member of String Ok("{}".toJsonString)
```

Tried just about anything i can think about and still not getting any progress.

Comment: you not import mapper  so try change to `import JacksonSerializer._`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the enclosing object differently from the implicit class inside it:

```
object JacksonSerializerHelpers {
  implicit val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  implicit class JacksonSerializer(val any: Any) {
    def toJsonString(implicit mapper: ObjectMapper): String = {
      val out = new StringWriter
      mapper.writeValue(out, any)
      out.toString()
    }
   }
}

import JacksonSerializerHelper.JacksonSerializer
Ok("{}".toJsonString)
```